# Python: summing up values from xlsx files saved in different folders

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, directory, subdirectory

Say I have a main folder which contains 20 sub folders. Each sub folder contains in turn one `xlsx` file only. I would like to sum up all the values located in the column A of each `xlsx` file, thus obtaining a `sub folder-sum value` pairing.

I would then like to repeat this for as many times as there are main folders.

Example:

```
MAIN FOLDER 1

   SUB FOLDER 1  SUB FOLDER 2

   file1.xlsx    file2.xlsx
   A1 17         A1 20
   A2 32         A2 30
   A3 24         A3 10
```

The corresponding results would be:

```
MAIN FOLDER 1    
sum1 = 17+32+24 = 73 -> Pairing 1= Sub folder 1; 73
sum2 = 20+30+10 = 60 -> Pairing 2= Sub folder 2; 60
...
```

I have written a piece of code but I am not sure the for loop is correct:

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook

directoryPath=r'C:\Users\MyDir'
os.mkdir(directoryPath)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directoryPath): #This confuses me as I don't see how the main folders are differentiated from the sub folders
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".xlsx")):

            #summing up
```

Comment: Check out the [documentation for `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop seems correct. `os.walk` returns you, for each element in the iterations, 3 values, the next dirs, the sub-directories in the current one, and the list of files in the current directory.

At this [link](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/) you can read the right way to use `os.walk`.

Look the following example. Suppose that I have the following directory structure:

```
+---main
|   |   
|   +---sub1
|   |       f2.xls
|   |       
|   \---sub2
|           f1.xls
```

This is basically your current code:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
for fname in fileList:
    print('\t%s' % fname)
```

Inside the first loop you iterate over the directories in your main folder. Each iteration will represent the pairing you are looking for. The second loop, `for fname in fileList`, lists the files in the folder stored in `dirName` only, so you can't pair wrong folders and files. In fact, this is your code output:

```
Found directory: C:/Users/cr01046/Desktop/main
Found directory: C:/Users/cr01046/Desktop/main\sub1
         f2.xls
Found directory: C:/Users/cr01046/Desktop/main\sub2
         f1.xls
```

Comment: In my case the sum value for `file1.xlsx` needs to be strictly related to the sub folder name. Same thing with `file2.xlsx` and so on. How can I be sure   that `os.walk` does not mess up with the pairing (sub folder; sum value)? I did not understand the scheme provided in the link you suggested, that's why I ask specifically.

Comment: With this loop you can't mess up the right paring order. I've edited my answer with a proper example.